# Custom datalayer for sylius

Tags: sylius

We are currently trying to figure out the best possible solution to integrate sylius with our ERP system through a REST api. 
What would be the best approach for swapping out the ORM layer and implementing a cached API layer instead?
Many actions like product creation will be disabled since they are managed in a different system so we only need some write actions like (order and payment). All other read actions will go through either elastic search or the API.

Is override every manager and repository the way to go or is there a better solution?

Thanks

Comment: This is an interesting concept, and I think one that's partially solved by [integration](https://github.com/Sylake/Sylakim) between Sylius and [Akeneo](http://www.akeneo.com/what-is-a-pim/). Akeneo being a PIM should be able use the data from your ERP.

Comment: Hi, I looked at Akeneo integration and it's basicly a push to Sylius if i'm not mistaken. That would be a last option to be honest.